# Populating a column in R based on conditions from another column using a for loop and if statements

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm looking at populating a different column in my data frame (project_data$Outlier) based on conditions from another column using a for loop and if statements. I'm trying to find outliers in my data based on the crop type from a different column (Commodity) as well as if the Total_Yield value is at or below a certain value. However, I keep getting different errors every time I try to run my code which is in the below pic:

[image]

Would someone be able to give me some guidance or a more accurate code script to utilize?

Comment: Please do not provide code in a picture, but paste it instead. Please also provide an example of your data using `dput()`.

Comment: Also a general comment: R vectorizes by default, which means that you don't need to build a for loop. `isTRUE` is redundant, as `==` will return a logical already (you're literally stating "if TRUE is TRUE").

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion for a simpler syntax using `dplyr::case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)
project_data %>%
  mutate(Outlier = case_when(
    Commodity == "BARLEY" & (Total_Yield < lower_bound_barley | Total_Yield > upper_bound_barley) ~ "Yes",
    Commodity == "CORN" & (Total_Yield < lower_bound_corn | Total_Yield > upper_bound_corn) ~ "Yes",
    #etc.
    TRUE ~ "No"
  )
```

To make it simpler than that, you might alternately keep your bounds in a table so that you don't have to code all that repetitive logic and store a bunch of separate variables.

e.g.

```
bounds <- tribble(
  ~Commodity, ~lower, ~upper,
  "CORN", 5, 50,
  #etc.
)
```

Then you could use a join to add the bounds to your data in line, and have the logic just refer to whether the yield is outside the range for each line's crop:

```
project_data %>%
  left_join(bounds) %>%   # this will use Commodity to pull in the respective
                          # "lower" and "upper" values from the "bounds" table
  mutate(Outlier = ifelse(Total_Yield < lower | Total_Yield > upper, "Yes", "No"))
```